# Filepath from a String in C#

Tags: c#, string

I need to get out of a String the Drive ,the directory and the extension. While the drive I go through I cant seem to get directory and extension to work.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class GetMethods
    {
        public String GetDrive(String Path)
        {
            String Drive;
            Drive = Path.Substring(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Drive: {0}", Drive);
            return Drive;
        }

        public String GetDirectory(String Path)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directorul: ");
            var start = Path.IndexOf(":") + 1;
            var match2 = Path.Substring(start, Path.IndexOf(".") - start);
            return Path;  
        }

        public String GetExtension(String Path)
        {
            String Extension;
            Extension = Path.Substring(0,3);
            Console.WriteLine("Extensia: {0}", Extension);
            return Extension;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String Path;
            GetMethods G = new GetMethods();
            Console.WriteLine("Introduceti calea: ");
            Path =Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Calea introdusa este:");
            Console.WriteLine(Path);

            Console.WriteLine(G.GetDrive(Path));
            Console.WriteLine(G.GetDirectory(Path));
            Console.WriteLine(G.GetExtension(Path));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have never used this Path class can you help me by using it on mine please?

Comment: i cant seem to get the Path working because im a noob.But how can i get the directory out of this String with Index of? C:

Comment: C:\Directory\File.txt

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to get all you want:

```
string path = @"C:\hello\world.txt";
var drive = Path.GetPathRoot(path); // "C:\"
var extension = Path.GetExtension(path); // ".txt"
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); // "C:\\hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use FileInfo class.

```
   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
   string ext = fi.Extension;
   string dir = fi.DirectoryName;
```

Please reffer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx